# How to add delay for javadock auto pop up in intellij idea while hovering over code

Tags: intellij-idea

I have added the following property in /bin/idea.properties file to enable auto pop up of javadoc while hovering over the code.

```
auto.show.quick.doc=true
```

Is there a way to set some delay on the popup? It pops up instantly.